# Откуда undefined при создании массива в цикле?

Tags: javascript

```js
let arr = [];

for (let i = 3; i <= 5; i++) {
  arr[i] = i;
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: а что по вашему должно быть по индексу 0, 1 и 2?

Comment: @Алексей а как получить такое `[3,4,5]`?

Comment: по-человечески делать цикл от 0 но заносить в массив i + delta, где delta - нужный старт - например

Comment: let arr = [];
let j = 0;
for (let i = 3; i <= 5; i++) {
  arr[j] = i; j++;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заполняйте массив через push

```js
let arr = [];

for (let i = 3; i <= 5; i++) {
  arr.push(i);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: минус не буду ставить, но в целом, вопрос был именно почему undefined. а варианты правильности, думаю, это уже как дополнение должно быть